# PHP beginner (from asp) using arrays with recordsets

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Am a PHP newbe coming from classic ASP.
It was good practice to open a recordset then put into an array using getrows
and close the the recordset and connection asap.

At the moment im using mysqli like this (TQ [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)):

```
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_servername, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
$sql = "SELECT product_name FROM table";
$Aprods = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $Aprods->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["product_name"];
}
$conn->close();
```

It all seems to work fine, but please advise if this is good practice (no arrays) and also do you close the connection? TQ

Comment: You are using arrays, read what fetch_assoc() does...  it fetches the data from the next row into an associative array.  You don't need to close the connection, it will close automatically at the end of execution and it may be faster to leave it open if you need another query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use prepared statements

```
$conObj = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db");
    //Creates sql template
    $prepare = $conObj->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users`");
    //Executes Query
      $prepare->execute();
      //Store Result
        $prepare->store_result();
        //And fetch
        while($prepare->fetch())
        {
           //db items
        } 

      //after you finish, close statement
      $prepare->close();
```

You can use that during CRUD(INSERT, SELECT, Delete, Update) operations and also is a good way to defend your application against SQL injections

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use ActiveRecord or ORM it is a normal practice.

I recoment to use PDO instead of MySQli. Its a similar library, but with pdo you can do: $array=$res->fetchAll() and get directly the result in an array.

Comment: TQ for info - am going to stick with mysqli for now - and try PDO on next project.